# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' - Electron

Tags: electron, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am working on a PDF viewer, basically, it's a [mozilla pdf.js project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). I cloned the repo and installed the dependencies and everything works fine, even when I try to build the project through `gulp generic`, it works without any issue.

The problem started when I have installed `electron`, to create a desktop version of the viewer, everything still worked even in the electron app, but I have used `const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')` to send messages to the main process, from the browser window. It works fine as well until I try to build the app using `gulp generic`, it throughs an error that says `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/*******/pdf.js/node_modules/electron'`. When I remove the `require('electron')` from the script it builds correctly.

**My Code**

```js
function webViewerLoad() {
  const isElectron =
    navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(" electron/") > -1;
  if (isElectron) {
    const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
    ipcRenderer.send("electron:reload", v);
  }
}


  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", webViewerLoad, true);
```

**The Error**

[image]

Comment: it looks like an error in electron itself. can you post your full code?

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming here it is: 

https://github.com/Crackiii/pdf.js/blob/b47ba883c7e5c440b09bb77ef862f81df065a61f/web/viewer.js#L203

Answer (score 1):

If someone is stuck in the same situation, I have solved it in a few steps after quiet research.

First of all, I have been using `electron.js` on my client-side code and the I have been using `const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");`. The browser doesn't know about require if you type in `require` in the browser console you'll get an error.

To surpass this issue, you have to use `browserify` or any similar tools. I have been using `gulp.js`, in my project.

Secondly, the file I have used `require('electron')` in, had multiple imports used `import file from 'somefile.js'`, so that's why `browserify` wasn't bundling it. All I had to require electron in a separate `.js` file and bundle it.

**ipc_electron.js**

```js
const ipcRenderer  = window.require('electron'). ipcRenderer;
//Clear the localstorage when application is quitted/closed
window.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
  if (data.type === "electron:reload") {
    ipcRenderer.send("electron:reload");
  }
});

ipcRenderer.on("pdf:url", _ => localStorage.clear());
```

**Gulp.js**

```js
gulp.task("browserify", () => {
  console.log();
  console.log("### Browserifying ipc_electron.js");
  return browserify("./web/ipc_electron.js", {
    debug: true,
    extensions: [".js"],
    ignoreMissing: true,
    detectGlobals: false,
    bare: true,
    debug: false,
    builtins: false,
    commondir: false,
  })
    .exclude("fs")
    .exclude("electron")
    .exclude("electron-updater")
    .exclude("electron-settings")
    .exclude("path")
    .exclude("url")
    .exclude("sqlite3")
    .exclude("express")
    .exclude("net")
    .exclude("body-parser")
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("ipc_electron_bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./web"));
});
```